# C# test file exists with linux home path of users in .NetCore Console app

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

NetCore 3.1 console app for linux.

And I want to test if a file exists from a path which a user entered.
But users are lazy and don't enter every time the absolute path.

```
string path = /home/username/myfile.test 
File.Exists(path)
```

this works fine but:

```
string path = ~username/myfile.test 
File.Exists(path)
```

this doesn't work and File.Exists return false.

Have anyone a solution to resolve a path with beginning ~?

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)` gets you the user's home folder. I'm not aware of anything which can resolve `~username`

Comment: @LeiYang `~username` is valid, and means "the home directory of the user called `username`". `~/` means "the home directory of the current user"

Comment: The Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) get the current user folder. But this don't solve my problem. User have to run the program as root. But the most users store the needed files in his own home folder. So the environment variable return /root and not the folder home folder of ~username which the user enters in the path.

Comment: If built in C# functions cannot do, how about call `echo ~user` and get process output?

Comment: @LeiYang yes this will work, i hoped anyone has maybe smarter or a built in C# function what can do this :)